# Build GDB Source Code for QNX (QNX App Debugging alternative)

Tags: debugging, gdb, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I’ve retrieved the GDB source from QNX CVS.

The error message indicates that the linker (ld) cannot find the definitions for various functions, such as
i386_linux_read_description, amd64_linux_read_description, amd64_collect_fxsave, amd64_collect_xsave,
amd64_supply_fxsave, amd64_supply_xsave, amd64_linux_gregset_reg_offset, amd64_supply_fxsave, and amd64_collect_fxsave.

1. Where to find the source code of above function or is it available in some library how to link that library?
2. IS any script availbe to use for the same?
   For Example : Using Standard GDB with pdebug:While a standard GDB client wouldn't directly work with pdebug, it's
   possible to bridge the gap using additional tools:
   QNX SDK: The QNX Software Development Platform (SDK) includes a wrapper script that allows executing standard GDB
   commands over the pdebug connection. This essentially translates GDB commands into the pdebug protocol, enabling limited
   use of regular GDB with pdebug.

3)Custom scripts: With advanced knowledge of both GDB and pdebug protocols, it's possible to write custom scripts or
wrappers that translate commands and bridge the communication gap.

Is any customer scripts availbe for use ?

4. We just need to avoid QNX Debugger. We just want to use open source debugger for QNX application if any other
   approched can u please inform?

To build GDB for QNX and debug QNX application

Comment: These missing functions are in gdb itself, in `i386-linux-tdep.c`, `amd64-linux-tdep.c`, and `amd64-tdep.c`.

Comment: Then why linker is not able to find the defination of fucntion and facing proglem to build gdb for QNX. IS any Script need to run to build QNX gdb? I am using http://f27svn.qnx.com/svn/repos/core-dev-tools/tools/ and using 710_release. How to build from that repository any steps avalible? There is no readme.txt availble Even I am facing problem in 800_release and qnx-800 as well. Please let me know any hint or steps require to build GDB for QNX